# Remove item from array if it exists in a 'disallowed words' array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => tom
    [1] => and
    [2] => jerry
)
```

And I also have a disallowed words array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => and
    [1] => foo
    [2] => bar
)
```

What I need to do is remove any item in the first array that also appears in the second array, in this instance for example, key 1 would need to be removed, as 'and' is in the disallowed words array.

Now I currently have this code, which does a foreach on the disallowed words and then uses array_search to find any matches:

```
$arr=array('tom','and','jerry');
$disallowed_words=array('and','or','if');
foreach($disallowed_words as $key => $value) {
    $arr_key=array_search($value,$array);
    if($arr_key!='') {
        unset($search_terms[$arr_key]);
    }
}
```

Now I know this code sucks, what I want to know is if there is a more efficient method of removing and item from an array where it exists in another array, especially if it negates using a foreach.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You want [`array_diff`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php).

> `array_diff` returns an array containing
>   all the entries from `array1` that are
>   not present in any of the other
>   arrays.

So you want something like:

```
$good = array_diff($arr, $disallowed_words);
```

Answer (score 0):

Uses of array_dif in php://It removes values from first array if that are exist in second array.

```
 $foo = array(1, 5, 9, 14, 23, 31, 45);
 $bar = array(14, 31, 36);
 $data = array_diff($foo,$bar);
 print_r($data);
```