# Excluding certain words from an array

Tags: php

The table below displays all words in the string `$commentstring`.   How can I exclude certain articles, prepositions, and verbs like "the, of, is"?

```
$words = explode(" ", $commentstring);

$result = array();
arsort($words);

foreach($words as $word) {    
  if(!is_numeric($word)){
    $result[$word]++;
    arsort($result);
  }
}

echo "<table>";

foreach($result as $word => $count1) {
  echo '<tr>';  
  echo '<td>';
  echo "$word";
  echo '</td>';

  echo '<td>';
  echo "$count1 ";
  echo '</td>';

  echo '</tr>';
}

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/1728727/212218

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several ways to do this, if you still want to count them but just not display them in the table, you could do:

```
$blacklist = array('the', 'is', 'a');

foreach($result as $word => $count1)
{
    if (in_array($word, $blacklist)) continue;

    ...
```

if you don't even want to count them, you can skip them in a similar way in your counting loop.