# Remove elements of one array if it is found in another

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove item from array if it exists in a 'disallowed words' array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728727/remove-item-from-array-if-it-exists-in-a-disallowed-words-array)

I have a dynamic string that clients will send and I want to create comma delimited tags from it:

```
$subject = "Warmly little in before cousin as sussex and an entire set Blessing it ladyship.";
print_r($tags = explode(" ", strtolower($subject)));
```

And yet, I want to delete a specific group of words (such as definite articles), but I want to delete the key and value of that word if it is in the exploded array:

```
$definite_articles = array('the','this','then','there','from','for','to','as','and','or','is','was','be','can','could','would','isn\'t','wasn\'t', 'until','should','give','has','have','are','some','it','in','if','so','of','on','at','an','who','what','when','where','why','we','been','maybe','further');
```

If one of these words in the `$definite_article` array are in the `$tags` array delete the key and value of that word and the new array will have these words taken out. I will have this array be used by `array_rand` to have a random group of words chosen out of it. I've tried many things to achieve my result, but nothing so far. Can someone help me find a resolve to this?

Comment: Look up array_diff () in the manual

Comment: look up at array-diff-key () and the reference link [ http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php ]

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You are looking for [`array_diff`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php):

```
$subject = "Warmly little in before cousin as sussex...";
$tags = explode(" ", strtolower($subject));

$definite_articles = array('the','this','then','there','from','for','to','as');

$tags = array_diff($tags, $definite_articles);
print_r($tags);
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/nbt4I)**.

Answer (score 57):

Sounds like an easy job for [**`array_diff()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php).

> ```
> array array_diff ( array $array1 , array $array2 [, array $... ] )
> ```
>
> Compares `array1` against `array2` and returns the difference.

Which basically means it will return `array1` after it's been stripped of all values which exist in `array2`.

Comment: `array_diff()` will retain the original array keys [of `array1`], which is what makes this statement true. You may or may not want this, but it is just something to be aware of.

Comment: array_diff() will retain the original array keys [of array1] - just wrap it in array_values - this will reset new array keys:

Example:
$new_array=array_values(array_diff($array1, $array2));