# Multiple array_filter and strpos

Tags: php, strpos, array-filter

I want to return array that does not contains a list of characters.

Below code works fine for one keyword (`'bc'`).

```
$array = array("abc", "def", "ghi");
$filterArray = array_filter($array, function ($var) {return(strpos($var, 'bc') === false);});
print_r($filterArray);
```

However, below code does not work when I try to filter out multiple keywords by using `$excludeKeyword_arr` and `foreach`.

```
$array = array("abc", "def", "ghi");
$excludeKeyword_arr = ("ab", "de");
foreach($excludeKeyword_arr as $exclude){
    $filterArray = array_filter($array, function ($var) {return(strpos($var, $exclude) === false);});
}
print_r($filterArray);
```

It should be return array instead of boolean type.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10589921/remove-elements-of-one-array-if-it-is-found-in-another

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems with the code. The first is that the scope of `$exclude` doesn't allow the closure to access it, simply solved by passing it in with `use`.

The second problem is that you always filter the original array (`$array`) and so the accumulative effect isn't achieved.  So here I copy the array and keep on filtering the copy (`$filterArray = array_filter($filterArray, function`)...

```
$array = array("abc", "def", "ghi");
$excludeKeyword_arr = array("ab", "de");
$filterArray = $array;
foreach($excludeKeyword_arr as $exclude){
    $filterArray = array_filter($filterArray, function ($var) use ($exclude) 
                     {return(strpos($var, $exclude) === false);});
}
print_r($filterArray);
```

which results in

```
Array
(
    [2] => ghi
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use preg_grep which will do the opposite and match the ones that has `bc` or `de` then array_diff.

```
$array = array("abc", "def", "ghi");
$excludeKeyword_arr = array("bc", "de");
$exclude_values = preg_grep("/". implode("|", $excludeKeyword_arr) . "/", $array);
$filterArray = array_diff($array, $values_with_bc);

print_r($filterArray); // [ 2 => "ghi"]
```

https://3v4l.org/IpNal

Comment: You need to change `$values_with_bc`, also update the *the ones that has **bc** or de then*

Answer (score 0):

For best performance, use a `foreach()` loop with a conditional `break` -- this way php doesn't need to perform useless iterations.

If the substring is found anywhere in the haystack string, remove it from the array of haystacks using `unset()`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/bYp2m))

```
$array = ["abc", "def", "ghi"];
$excludeKeyword_arr = ["ab", "de"];

foreach ($array as $index => $haystack) {
    foreach ($excludeKeyword_arr as $needle) {
        if (strpos($haystack, $needle) !== false) {
            unset($array[$index]);
            break;
        }
    }
}
var_export(array_values($array));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'ghi',
)
```

A word of caution: if entertaining the notion of a `preg_` call for brevity's sake, understand that for reliability/stability, you must apply `preg_quote()` to each values in the needles array if there is any chance of characters with special meaning to the regex engine.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the same as @Andreas, but reindexing in the end.

```
$array           = ["ab", "def", "ghi"];
$excludeKeywords = ["ab", "de"];

$pattern = implode("|", $excludeKeywords);
$result = preg_grep("/$pattern/i", $array);

// Positive (Reindex)
print_r(array_values($result));

// Negative (Reindex)
$result = array_diff($array, $result);
print_r(array_values($result));
```

### [Demo](https://ideone.com/34A3Nq)

Read more:

Pipe **( ab|de )** = https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html

---